# Pagination link is not working /page/2 - NOT FOUND - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, http-status-code-404

I need to create a paginator in my blog page, until this its good, but when i click in a link of my pagination i got NOT FOUND page, i need to know if i need to able something in the panel to wordpress able the access to ?page=N

function:

```
    function get_pagination($the_query) {
    global $paged;
    $total_pages = $the_query->max_num_pages;
    $big = 999999999;

    if ($total_pages > 1) {
        ob_start();

        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $paged,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text' => '',
            'next_text' => ''
        ));
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return null;
}
```

my blog code

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
        // echo $paged;
        $produtos = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type'      => 'blog',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'orderby'        => 'date',
            'order'          => 'asc',
            'paged'          => $paged,
            'tax_query'      => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'categorias',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => ACTIVE
                )
            )
        ));

        while ( $produtos->have_posts() ) : $produtos->the_post();

        //CONTENT

        endwhile;

        echo get_pagination($produtos);
```

Comment: Lots of similar problems: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=pagination+not+working+is%3Aq

Answer (score 38):

Go to admin Dashboard then `Settings->Reading` then set `Blog pages show at most` is equal to you query `posts_per_page`. So in your query if you set `posts_per_page => 2` then `Blog pages show at most`will be `2`

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple like this, I tried so many fixes and has taken me days to get to the bottom of the issue. Thank you!

Comment: fuck, how come can't i bypass this with code??? at least, problem solved. thanks.

Answer (score 19):

This is what I found and resolved the issue I had!

> [...] I needed to go into the wp-admin page (the wordpress dashboard)
>   and go to Settings then Reading and in the "Blog pages show at most"
>   field I changed the value from '10' to '6' (the number of posts I
>   indicated in
>   `$wp_query->query('showposts=6&cat=1'.'&paged='.$paged);`)

Answer (score 2):

use following paged query

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; }

    $produtos = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type'      => 'blog',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby'        => 'date',
            'order'          => 'asc',
            'paged'          => $paged,
            'tax_query'      => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'categorias',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => ACTIVE
                )
            )
        ));

        while ( $produtos->have_posts() ) : $produtos->the_post();

        //CONTENT

        endwhile;

        echo get_pagination($produtos);
```

Comment: But my problem isnt about the paginate creation, but is about wordpress not understanding that /page/ is not a new page.

Comment: @gabrielbuzzi this wordpress page not found error arise while get the posts in custom templates, have you tried with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your .htaccess file. It should contain a rewrite rule to enable pagination with slashes.

Please see: 
"Using pretty permalinks" - http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Answer (score -1):

```
 Problem: When we click on next page then wordpress redirects on first 
 -------  page or on same pag.


Solution: put this code snippet in your themes functions.php file.
--------


add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'pif_disable_redirect_canonical');

function pif_disable_redirect_canonical($redirect_url)
{
    if (is_singular()) $redirect_url = false;
    return $redirect_url;
}


 ---------------------------------------------------
! it has worked for me , I hope it works for you
```

Answer (score -5):

Go to your wordpress Dashboard Settings then Reading and in the "Blog pages show at most" field, changed the value from '10' to '1'
cheers!